# Active Directory Last Password Change date and time

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, active-directory

I an writing code in C# to find the Last Password Change date and Time in Active Directory. I have been able to find the date seeing some examples, but not the correct timestamp. Can anyone please help regarding this? My code so far is:

```
DirectoryEntry de = (DirectoryEntry)foundUser.GetUnderlyingObject();
if (de.Properties["pwdLastSet"].Value != null)
{
     LargeInteger liAcctPwdChange = de.Properties["pwdLastSet"].Value as LargeInteger;
     long dateAcctPwdChange = (((long)(liAcctPwdChange.HighPart) << 32) + (long)liAcctPwdChange.LowPart);
     Label1.Text = DateTime.FromFileTime(dateAcctPwdChange).ToShortDateString();
}
```

Comment: Change your ToShortDateString...  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: FWIW, this field is **erased** if you check the box for "User must change password at next logon".

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
long dateAcctPwdChange = (((long)(liAcctPwdChange.HighPart) << 32) + (long)liAcctPwdChange.LowPart);
Label1.Text = DateTime.FromFileTime(dateAcctPwdChange).ToShortDateString();
```

To this

```
long dateAcctPwdChange = (((long)(liAcctPwdChange.HighPart) << 32) + (uint)liAcctPwdChange.LowPart);
Label1.Text = DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(dateAcctPwdChange).ToString();
```

Changing the last `long` to `uint` and `FromFileTime` to `FromFileTimeUtc`

For a quick reference example from MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180872(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: The answer above does not show how to display the timestamp. I am getting the date correct, but how to get the time?

Comment: Remove `ToShortDateString()`

Comment: I removed ToShortDateString(), however I needed to add .ToString() That gives me as result "5/4/2016 8:18:08 PM". But the value in AD is "5/4/2016 4:18:08 PM Eastern Daylight Time"

Comment: Have you tried changing `DateTime.FromFileTime` to `DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc`? It sounds like a timezone issue

Comment: Yes, I am using Label1.Text = DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(dateAcctPwdChange).ToString();

Comment: This worked: Label1.Text = DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(dateAcctPwdChange).ToLocalTime().ToString();

Comment: Good, was about to suggest something like that. It's with the timezones.

Answer (score 0):

in case anybody still looking for a working code, here is my working version:

```
using System;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Set up a PrincipalContext to connect to your Active Directory domain
        using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "YourDomain"))
        {
            // Find the user by their username
            UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, "Username");
            if (user != null)
            {
                // Retrieve the "Password last set" attribute
                DateTime? passwordLastSet = user.LastPasswordSet;

                if (passwordLastSet != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Password Last Set: " + passwordLastSet.Value.ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Password Last Set information is not available.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("User not found in Active Directory.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: fwiw, this field is **erased** if you check the box for "User must change password at next logon".